# Add data type into database using multiple variables

Tags: php, database, date

It's my first time posting here.
I'm trying to add a data type column into my database, but I think that the yyyy-mm-dd format is very confusing. I want the user to enter a date that is dd-mm-yyyy format. I think that the easiest way is to make $day, $month, $year variables and add them all to the same column in the database. Is there any way to do this? Or is there any easier way to change the date format to dd-mm-yyyy for the user to insert?

Comment: You can use date formatting commands to show the date in any format you like once it's been retrieved from the database.  This would be far better than creating multiple columns for year, month, day, etc, because if you did that the database would no longer be aware that the data in question was temporal in nature and you'd lose several options for manipulating it as dates.

Comment: The problem is not showing the date afterwards. I want the user to be able to to enter the date in the form that i have created in the format dd-mm-yyyy.

Comment: You can also use date formatting to convert dates from the format you want to display into the format the database requires before storing them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$date = '20';
$month = '04';
$year = '2019';
$date = $date.'-'.$month.'-'.$year;
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date));
?>
```

Considering your day, month & year are available in the variables you mentioned, the above code should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

=> Tyr this to change date format..

```
$originalDate = "2019-02-04";
$newDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```